# multiprocessing.queue.get() blocks and does not return

Tags: python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing

I am building a webserver on an embedded Linux device with very little RAM (only 256 MB). That webserver should be able to issue shell commands using `subprocess.check_output`, but since each `check_output` seems to require about as much RAM available as the parent process consumes, I am using multiprocessing to create a second process right at the start when Python still does not consume much memory. This process then uses a `multiprocessing.Queue` to receive commands from the main process, executes them and returns the output using another `multiprocessing.Queue`. This used to work but I seem to have some kind of race condition that causes the whole thing to get stuck.

This is my minimum test case that replicates the problem:

```
# shwrapper.py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(iq,oq):
    oq.put("Ready")
    while True:
        oq.put(iq.get()+" out")

def init():
    iq = Queue()
    oq = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(iq,oq,))
    p.start()
    print oq.get()
    iq.put("test")
    print(oq.get())
init()
```

If I try to import this I get this result:

```
>>> import shwrapper
Ready
```

Here it get's stuck. Now I issue a KeyboardInterrupt:

```
^CProcess Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python27.zip/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "shwrapper2.py", line 17, in <module>
    init()
  File "shwrapper2.py", line 15, in init
    print(oq.get())
  File "/usr/lib/python27.zip/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
KeyboardInterrupt
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python27.zip/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "shwrapper2.py", line 6, in f
    oq.put(iq.get()+" out")
  File "/usr/lib/python27.zip/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
    res = self._recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

So as you can see, it get's stuck at iq.get() in f. The iq-Queue reports to always be empty, no matter what I put into it. The oq-Queue on the other hand works as expected. Any ideas what I can do here?

My system here is Python 2.7.3 running on Linux 2.6.29.6 on a PowerPC.

If I run it on the Python 2.7.10 on my Windows computer everything goes through fine.

I know Python 2.7.3 and Linux 2.6.29 are ancient, but there are no newer builds from the manufacturer and the system is kinda locked down.

Comment: Thanks for this post. I ran into the same issue with Python 3.6 and MacOS Mojave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally fixed it by using `multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue` instead of `multiprocessing.Queue`. According to the documentation there should be no difference in that respect, but in the source the `SimpleQueue` uses `Lock`s that make it work with multiple processes.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`get_notwait`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get_nowait) instead of [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get). for example:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
q = Queue()
try:
    q.get_nowait()
except:
    print("queue is empty")
```

or you can add `timeout` to `get` method. for example:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
q = Queue()
try:
    q.get(timeout=1)
except:
    print("queue is empty.")
```

Also, you can only catch `Empty` exception instead of general exception:

```
from queue import Empty
try:
    q.get_nowait()
except Empty:
    print("queue is empty")
```